# Extract custom fields from results of get_results method in WordPress $wpdb

Tags: php, custom-fields, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I'm working on WordPress json api plugin. I created my custom controller, I want to retrieve posts as  Json format, my work was as below :

My php code is:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select * from $wpdb->posts where $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
            $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' ",  $key)); 
            $count = 0 ; 
           foreach( $rows as $post ) {    
           $output[] = array( 'id' => $post->ID, 'title' => $post->post_title, 'price' =>$post->custom_fields->price);
           ++$count ; 
           }
        if($count == 0){
          $data = array ('status'=>'ok', 'count'=> $count , 'result'=> "No data found "); 
          }else
         {
          $data = array ('count'=> $count , 'result'=> $output); 
         }
       header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
       return $data; 
       }
```

Json result as below:

```
   {
 "status": "ok",
 "count": 10,
 "result": [
  {
  "id": "51",
  "title": "a",
  "price": null
  },
  {
  "id": "82",
  "title": "b",
  "price": null
    },
     }
```

Why price is set to null, what the correct syntax to extract price from custom fields from posts in WordPress?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Do a `print_r($rows)`, and see what you have inside. From your result `$post->custom_fields->price` seems to be `null`...

Answer (score 0):

thank you dears for your quick help , i found the solution , i had to use : get_post_meta function to retrieve price , so this line :

```
   $output[] = array( 'id' => $post->ID, 'title' => $post->post_title,'price' =>$post->custom_fields->price);
```

will be as following  :

```
 $output[] = array( 'id' => $post->ID, 'title' => $post->post_title, 'price' =>get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true));
```

thank  you ,